# Why multiple box-shadow is getting squarer?

Tags: css

I was trying to solve this [CSS battle](https://cssbattle.dev/play/94). I tried to use a rounded div with border and then just add `box-shadow` for every circle around the center circle. But for some reason the 5th `box-shadow` doesn't look like a right circle, it's getting squared. Why is this happening and how could I fix it?

```css
body {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #0E2E2C;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #F3AC3C;
  border: 8px solid #0E2E2C;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 12px #F3AC3C,
              0 0 0 22px #0E2E2C,
              0 0 0 32px #998235,
              0 0 0 44px #0E2E2C,
              0 0 0 51px #F3AC3C, /* this one is starting to look more squarer */
              0 0 0 63px #0E2E2C,
              0 0 0 68px #F3AC3C;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

It's not about how to just solve this CSS challenge cause I solved it with adding another circle with border and 2 box-shadows around the circle with 4 box-shadows, but I want to have only one box-shadow property here, not 2 circles or radial-gradient. Maybe I just don't know something about `box-shadow` to use it right. Please help.

Comment: they changed the implementation of box-shadow (since a few months now)

Comment: For what it's worth: this issue appears to be specific to Chrome's implementation (and likely other chromium browsers, though I haven't confirmed); both Safari and Firefox render them all as circles.

Comment: @DanielBeck that's correct! I see all circles too and my browser is Safari.

Answer (score 0):

It gets better when I keep adding to border width. I changed 8px to 20px. I think because the wider circles get, they need more material to maintain the roundness.

```css
body {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #0E2E2C;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #F3AC3C;
  border: 20px solid #0E2E2C;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 12px #F3AC3C, 0 0 0 22px #0E2E2C, 0 0 0 32px #998235, 0 0 0 44px #0E2E2C, 0 0 0 51px #F3AC3C, 0 0 0 63px blue, 0 0 0 68px #F3AC3C;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: it gets rounder, but it's bigger now, so it's different figure

Comment: @j-0-n-e-z I tried reducing from the size of the shadows. It does bring down the size a bit but then the middle one which is the border itself remains big.